# Create a simple php array using mysql rows...

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql code like this...

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`product_id`, `model`, `sku`) VALUES
(61, 'one-s 1407', ''),
(72, 'one-s 1408', ''),
(88, 'one-s 1409', ''),
(91, 'one-s 1403', ''),
(95, 'one-s 1404', '');
```

Now i would like to extract the product_id and create a php array like this..

```
$productid = array(61,72,88,91,95);
```

PLEASE NOTE:

The mysql code i given just for sample. But i have more than 1000 rows and 15 columns in my table.

I would be very happy if someone give me some php snippet which does this job easily. Thanks

Comment: Where is your data stored? Is it in a database? because it seems like you're trying to parse a `dump.sql` file

Comment: @hsanders He's tried asking us to give him some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a technic :

```
<?php

// Query the database
SELECT product_id FROM product

// Loop
$Products = array();
while(){
    $Products[] = $Row->product_id;
}

print_r($Products);

?>
```

Try something by yourself. Use PDO extension to create your query and then use the method `fetch` to get your data in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");    

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $array [] = $row['p']
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated. Don't use them.

Comment: @Matt Dont be so foolish, anyone asking such a question doesnt know PDO yet. And if he was, why has he not used Paramterised queries. This should have been obviuos.

Comment: In that case, it's clear that you know to use PDOs. You shouldn't be advising people to use deprecated functionality.

Comment: @Matt His question is how to append to arrays. That can be learnt in a minute. To learn PDO takes about a day and he probably doesnt know OOP yet either. But, each to their own!

Comment: I agree that learning PDO doesn't require to understand so much OOP and also should be teach first since PDO isn't that hard to understand and to make in practice.

Comment: @DavidBélanger may i know why you capitlised your variables? PHP convention dictates to use capital only when defining Classes!

Comment: @yehuda2 I am using my own convention and this has nothing to do versus the security and speed.

Comment: @DavidBélanger no but its a bad habit which as you can see by yourself doesnt change. Everyone changes to PDO in the end anyway

Comment: @yehuda2 from what i've read there are two solutions to this issue. One, an easy way to understand, is deprecated, and Two, using PDO. if this is the case, why not edit your answer to include both ways, with a description something like "This is the fast, deprecated way of doing this, <deprecated code> HOWEVER, This new way is the recommended way of doing it <new code>, but requires some knowledge of how PDO works. For reference, here are some guides for learning PDO <x,y,z>" that way the OP has the choice. This is the difference between an adequate answer and an outstanding answer.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
$pid= array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$pid[] = $row['product_id']
 }
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated. Don't use them.